# Removing Extra Caption tag around image on post of WordPress

Tags: posts, post-content

I am facing an issue when i use get_the_content() function.  It displays the post content but the image in beginning of the content has some extra text around. My code is:

```
<div class="thecontent" itemprop="articleBody">
   <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

I also tried

```
<div class="thecontent" itemprop="articleBody">
   <?php $content= get_the_content();  
         echo apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
   ?>
</div>
```

But in this case picture isn't showing at all.

Output:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that `get_the_content` doesn't render shortcode (which is what you're seeing). I would check out using: `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $postid) );` you can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270147/wordpress-shortcode-doesnt-work-when-getting-post-content-using-function-get-p

Comment: It's not working in my case. :(

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: did you try just "the_content()" instead of "echo get_the_content()"?  Alternatively, if you don't want captions, why not remove them from the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the shortcode executes, save the content to a variable, then run `do_shortcode` on the saved variable.

```
<div class="thecontent" itemprop="articleBody">
    <?php $content = get_the_content();
    echo do_shortcode($content); ?>
</div>
```

The difference is, echoing just literally echoes whatever has been grabbed. PHP's built-in functions don't have any special way to process shortcodes so they just output as they've been told. By using a WP-specific function, WordPress parses whatever the content is and displays it. This works even if you have no shortcodes in the content.

Comment: Its not showing even all post. :(

Comment: you'll need to echo the do_shortcode...

"echo do_shortcode($content);"

Comment: Corrected above. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you had originally, `echo get_the_content();` doesn't work because the `do_shortcode` callback isn't applied when calling [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/), but it is when calling [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/). That's why the caption shortcode isn't being converted into its corresponding HTML.

There is almost never a reason to `echo get_the_content()` because that's basically what `the_content()` does.

```
<div class="thecontent" itemprop="articleBody">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

If, for whatever reason, your use can necessitates using `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()`, you need to make sure that the `do_shortcode` callback is applied before printing the HTML. So there are a couple ways to fix that. One (that should work) is by applying the `the_content` filter to the `get_the_content()` function.

```
//* In your index.php (or wherever template file)
printf( 
  '<div class="thecontent" itemprop="articleBody">%1$s</div>',
  apply_filters( 'the_content', $content )
);
```

This is basically what you tried in your question. I write it like this because it's clearer, to me, what this code does. To be clear, this should work. Since it's not, there is a filter hooked to `the_content` that's messing it up added by your theme or a plugin. Make sure to disable all plugins and disable any other part of your theme that filters `the_content`.

Another way to do this is to force the shortcodes to do their thing. This is what WebElaine says in her answer. I'd do it slightly differently, but again, the same concept.

```
//* Again, in a template file
printf(
  <div class="thecontent" itemprop="articleBody">%1$s</div>,
  do_shortcode( get_the_content() )
);
```

There's also a way to do this in your functions.php, or another file included from your functions.php, or even a plugin. What you can do is hook into `the_content` and add the wrapper there.

```
//* In your functions.php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_283971_the_content', 1000 );
function wpse_283971_the_content( $content ) {
  return sprintf( '<div class="thecontent" itemprop="articleBody">%1$s</div>', $content );
}

//* In your template file
the_content();
```

I'm guessing that you're trying to `echo get_the_content()` instead of just using `the_content()` is because `the_content()` wasn't working. You need to find the filter that's causing the problem with `the_content`. From the looks of it, one of the filters is forgetting to return its result.